onchange event not being triggered if input file is empty
I have this function, which asks the user for a file, and returns the File if selected, and (should) return null if nothing is selected.
async pickFile(allowed_extensions?: string[]): Promise<File | null> {
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'file';
    input.accept = allowed_extensions?.join(',') ?? '*';
    input.click();

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        input.onchange = () => {
            if (input.files && input.files.length > 0) {
                resolve(input.files[0]);
            } else {
                resolve(null);
            }
        };
    });
}

If I select a file and confirm, it works normally. However, if I close the selection window, it seems the onchange event is not triggered. Is this behavior expected? If so, how could I handle it?
Reproducible example

Please include a [mre].

Included it to the question.

Still not reproducible since allowed_extensions isn't defined.

Sorry, just fixed it.

"However, if I close the selection window, it seems the onchange event is not triggered. Is this behavior expected?" - well if you just dismiss the selection dialog, without making any selection - then what value would you have actually changed?

onchange isn't triggered when closing the window.
You should add another eventlistener to the cancel event that will trigger when you close the popup:


function pickFile() {
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = 'file';
  input.click();
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    input.onchange = () => {
      console.log('onchange triggered');
      if (input.files && input.files.length > 0) {
        resolve(input.files[0]);
      } else {
        resolve(null);
      }
    };
    input.addEventListener("cancel", () => {
        console.log('Input canceled');
      resolve(null)
    });
  });
}
<button type="button" onclick="pickFile()">Click Me!</button>




So simple! Somehow I didn't know about this event. Thanks for your time!
